# Combination of balls on a shelf

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm struggling to come up with a formula to find the number of ways I can put 3 identical balls on a shelf that has 8 positions so that no ball is adjacent to another ball. Can you assist me with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the trick.  Don't allocate the balls.  Allocate the empty spaces.

This would be one acceptable arrangement.

-o-o--o-

There must be 2 empty space between the balls, leaving 3 empty spaces that you have freedom to allocate. and 4 locations they could go into.

This falls under what are called "stars and bars" problems.

There are 3 stars (spaces you have freedom to allocate)  and 3 bars (baseballs) that partition your shelf into bins.

${6\choose 3}$

Comment: It looks like our answers disagree: I got ${8\choose 3}-2{7\choose 2}+{6\choose 1}=20$, while you got $35$. Mind reading my answer to see if I'm mistaken? Also, by empty spaces, what do you mean that there are $3$ that you have the freedom to place?

Comment: You are right.  3 stars and 3 bars... ${6\choose 3}$

Comment: How would the stars and bars problem work for 10 positions and 4 balls, i.e. how do I determine the number of empty spaces I have freedom to allocate?

Comment: 10 positions, 4 balls... 4 spots taken up by balls, 3 spots mandatory in between spacing.  3 free-to-allocate spaces, 4 balls. ${7\choose 3}$

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the Principal of Inclusion-Exclusion, aka PIE? If you are, this will be easy, but if not, I'll explain what I'm doing. If I start with ${8\choose 3}$, I count all ways to place the three balls in the $8$ places, but it'll unfortunately also count the ones with some balls adjacent to each other.

But how many ways can I have some balls adjacent? I could have the first two adjacent to each other, or I could have the last two adjacent to each other. In each case, there are ${7 \choose 2}$ ways for this to happen, since, in the first case, I compress the first and second ball into one, since whenever I place the first ball, I have to place the second to the right of it. Hence, I subtract $2{7\choose 2}$ from ${8\choose 3}$.

However, there's another problem: this double counts the "bad" placements, since I could have a placement that has both the first two adjacent to each other, and the last two adjacent to each other. Namely, having the three in a row. There are ${6\choose 1}$ ways this can happen, since once I place the first one, the other two go directly to the right of it. Hence, including and excluding certain placements gives me ${8\choose 3}-2{7\choose 2}+{6\choose 1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Another mental picture that allows one to reach the same correct answer:

Assume the three identical balls are ***black***. Take three identical ***white*** balls, and glue each black ball to a white ball.  Throw in an additional three ***white*** balls.

You now have $6$ objects:  $3$ identical single white balls and $3$ identical black-white pairs.

Arrange them in a row on a shelf, working from left to right, while agreeing to always put down a black-white pair with the white ball to the right. Then make all the white balls disappear.  You have the desired final condition.

You can arrange these items in $N$ ways:$$N =\frac{6!}{3! \times 3!}=20$$I came up with this awkward model in attempting to find the probability that the results of a Lotto 6/49 draw, when arranged in numerical order, will have no consecutive numbers...